# php&mysql running queries within loops

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with around 3000 records which amongst other things holds the following information.
|ID|REGION|AREA|DISTRICT|CHECKED|

Each district belongs to an area, and each area to a region.
There are 4 regions, each of which contains 5 or 6 areas. Each area contains 5 or 6 districts.

For each REGION, AREA and DISTRICT I need the following information.
Total records, Total checked, Total unchecked.

The way I am currently doing this is by running queries from within loops within loops. This is resulting in 375 queries being run to extract the information I need to display a page.

Is this avoidable and can someone point me in the right direction? (I'm using PHP and mysql)

Thanks

Comment: please post table definition, sample input and desired output

Comment: Please post your code, and your DB scheme

Comment: Probably something like `SELECT area, region, district, COUNT(id) AS no, checked FROM table GROUP BY district, checked;` and `... GROUP BY area, checked;` and `... GROUP BY region, checked;` This will give you 3 queries with region, area and district totals on checked